# Mysql на локальном компьютере

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть хост, не локальный, а проблема такова: 
Возможно-ли открыть mysql базу данных на локальном компьютере?
Если это возможно то какое ПО мне нужно?

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность на машине с БД открыть порт "в мир", то можно воспользоваться им. При этом на своей домашней машине подключаться к БД по ip удаленной.

Более безопасным способом будут VPN или SSH подключения.

В случае с VPN подключение можно будет проводить по IP внутри приватной сети.

В случае с SSH, если на удаленной машине *nix, то делается это стандартными средствами (localhost - машина, c которой нужно подключиться к БД, mymachine.org - машина, на которой работает БД):

```
ssh -f -N -L 3306:localhost:3306 username@mymachine.org
```

При этом появляется открытый локальный порт 3306 и подключение можно будет проводить на localhost:3306. Если на локальной машине у вас Windows, можно воспользоваться программой PuTTY, настройки ее аналогичные прописанным будут. Соединение будет шифрованное, потому безопасное. Более подробно можно почитать про проброс [на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/81607/)

PS этот вопрос уместнее задать на руткоде

Answer (score 0):

Да можно. Гугли : SQL Manager for MySQL, вроде можно просто текстовиком.